# Можно ли сделать чтобы все циклы while выполнялись оновременно?

Tags: python, циклы, while, for

Вот код как заставить его работать?

```
while 1 < 2:
     while 1 < 2:
         key_down = input
         valut_kurs = gold / valute
         if key_down == 'курс':
             print(valut_kurs)
     while 1 < 2:
         time.slepp(10)
         random = random.randint(1, 100)
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(120)
         if support < 50:
          print ("ты проиграл ты перестал быть правителем")
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(5)
         support = support - 1
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(60)
         Time = time + 1
     while 1 < 2:
         time.sleep(12)
         gold = gold - 1000/7 * Army
time.sleep(5)
print(gold)
print(valute_kurs)
print(support)
```

Comment: вроде можно, это многопоточное программирование

Comment: Советую удалить этот код и начать заново, предварительно подумав и разобравшись, как работают циклы и вообще все остальное.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, избавиться от бесконечных циклов `while 1 < 2`, без оператора `break` они не имеют конца. Далее, если я не ошибаюсь, все ваши циклы можно вместить в один, если вы хотели чтобы все эти действия выполнялись последовательно. В целом необходимо переписать программу с нуля, разобравшись с тем, что вы хотите получить при ее выполнении, и написав соответствующий код.

В рамках вашей программы реализовать одновременное выполнение нескольких циклов невозможно.